# c# copy array of structures as bytes using Marshal.Copy()

Tags: c#, bitmap, marshalling, lockbits

I'm having a problem with copying an array of structures as a byte array. The structures are simple RGB structs.

```
public struct RGBColor { byte r; byte g; byte b; }
```

Then I have an array of `RGBColor[]` that represents a scanline that I want to copy to a `Bitmap` after I've called `LockBits()`. It will only allow an array of `byte[]` to be copied using `Marshal.Copy()`.

If I understand correctly (keep in mind I DO NOT UNDERSTAND), I need to marshal the `RGBColor[]` array to a byte array, copy the data to that new `byte[]` array, and then copy that array to the bitmap. It seems like there's an unnecessary copying operation occuring and I have an intermediate `byte[]` array just serving as a middle man.

Isn't there any way I can cast `RGBColor[]` to `byte[]` so I can just copy it directly to the locked bitmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marshal.Copy() isn't the right method in this case, it forces you to cough up the byte[] and that hurts in more than one way.  What you really need is a method that copies from an IntPtr to an IntPtr so that simply pinning the array gets the job done, avoiding the copy and the structure layout hassle.  The .NET framework doesn't have one.

But Windows does, you can pinvoke the `memcpy()` function.  You can tinker the declaration to make it accept your RGBColor[] array.  Like this:

```
  [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  private static extern int memcpy(IntPtr dest, RGBColor[] srce, int bytes);
```

The first argument is slightly tricky.  You'll need:

```
  BitmapData bd = ...
  IntPtr dest = new IntPtr((long)bd.Scan0 + scanline * bd.Stride);
```

Comment: I am familiar with Win32 API's. Never knew I could use them in this way in .NET languages. Do you know if these directive imports will work correctly in Mono on Linux?